# Sorting array. java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I've been trying everything to sort out this array and seem not working. Every Examobject in the array has **String firstName, String lastName, int ID, char examType('M' or 'F'), and int score**. The array should be sorted by the first examType -'M' followed immediately by the final 'F' of the same person. Also having trouble with the line **if(position[i*2].getID() == r[i+1].getID())**. Total 10 objects. I tried to match the exam objects by the ID but still not working. ONLY one loop is allowed!

```
public static Exam[] collateExams(Exam[] exams)
    {
        Exam [] r = new Exam[10];
        r = exams;
        //Exam [] finalExam = new Exam[50];
        int[] position = new int[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < exams.length; i++)
        {
            if(r[i].getExamType() == 'M')
            {   

                r[i*2] = new Exam(r[i*2].getFirstName(), r[i*2].getLastName(),
                                  r[i*2].getID(), r[i*2].getExamType(), r[i*2].getScore());

                position[i*2] = r[i*2].getID();

                if(position[i*2].getID() == r[i+1].getID())
                    r[i+1] = new Exam(r[i+1].getFirstName(), r[i+1].getLastName(),
                              r[i+1].getID(), r[i+1].getExamType(), r[i+1].getScore()); 



            }

            /*if((r[i].getExamType() == 'F') && (position[i] == r[i].getID()))
            {

            }*/

        }

        return r;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `Arrays.sort` with your custom `Comparator`which will use values you want.

Comment: Is this an assignment?

Comment: Have you considered using an `ArrayList` ? It's surely much more Java-like approach, plus you can use the sorting methods.

Comment: Sorry, but ArrayList is not allowed.

Comment: Mike is this an assignment? If so are you allowed to use sort or do you have to write your own?

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
class ExamComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Exam e1, Exam e2) {
        return e1.getExamType() == e2.getExamType() ? 0 : (e1.getExamType() == 'F' ? 1 : -1);
    }
}

Arrays.sort(exams, new ExamComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.sort` with your custom `Comparator` which will use values you want.

Comment: It is more advice, than answer, that is why I posted it as comment. Answers should at least contain simple example describing your solution so OP (and others) could easily understand what you mean.

Comment: @Pshemo I disagree. This is an answer. Better answers can be written, and they would probably do what you recommend. But the OP can follow this, looking up documentation or Googling "Comparator" as needed. A future visitor is far more likely to notice this answer here than the comment, and it would be helpful to them, which makes it a good (not great) answer. In general err on the side of answer, SO works better that way even though a lot of people try to overuse comments IMO.

Comment: @Pshemo btw, I know I lifted your answer nearly verbatim to partly make this point - if you want to post it yourself as is or fleshed out, I'll delete mine out of fairness.

Comment: @Mike `Arrays.sort` is for arrays, not lists.

Comment: @djechlin OK, I wasn't saying that it is not an answer at all, but it is more like advice. You are right, it can be useful, but there are so many ways which could make it great answer it is just pity that it doesn't have more content. BTW it doesn't bother me that my it looks same as my comment, so don't worry about it. It is just I want Stack Overflow to have answer which could stay on their own, without need to look for documentation or Google.

Answer (score 0):

As @djechlin explained you can use ,`Arrays.sort` with your own custom comparator like mentioned in below example , You can use List or Array whatever you want its upto you ,

```
List<String> list=Arrays.asList("XYZ","ABC","DEF");
String [] stringArray=new String[]{"XYZ","ABC","DEF"};

Arrays.sort(stringArray,new Comparator(){
    public int compare(Object one,Object two){
        String first=(String)one;
        String second=(String)two;
        return first.compareTo(second);             
    }
});
for(String s:stringArray){
    System.out.print(s+"\t");
}

Collections.sort(list,new Comparator(){
    public int compare(Object one,Object two){
        String first=(String)one;
        String second=(String)two;
        return first.compareTo(second);             
    }
});
 System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**

```
ABC DEF XYZ // for Arrays.sort
[ABC DEF XYZ]// for Collections.sort
```

Now Coming to your actuall problem

> The array should be sorted by the first examType -'M' followed
>   immediately by the final 'F' of the same person

You have to create your own custom comparator which does the sorting based on examType